# How do I access the engagement info of my FB posts to my FB page via the API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What I would like to do is, in an automated way, pull the basic analytics (# of views/likes/comments) on a post that I have published to my FB page.

I am looking through the Graph API docs and I am not seeing anything that allows me to do so.

I am not too familiar with FB's publicly available APIs though, so I could very easily be missing it.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post#edges

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. That's exactly what I wanted to know. You can go ahead and add that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post#edges lists several edges, amongst them `/likes` and `/comments`, which both offer a `total_count` property, and
`/shared_posts`.

If you need more detailed information than that, you might also want to check out the available `insights`, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights#post_impressions